# How to check, if a value is an integer with plpgsql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

i am using this function in a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xx() RETURNS trigger AS $xx$
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO my_log (x, y, z) VALUES (NEW.x, NEW.y, current_setting('myvar.user'));
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$xx$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

now i would like to check, if 'myvar.user' is a valid integer, and if not, do another INSERT statement.

how would i do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT  current_setting('myvar.user') ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [archives.postgresql.org](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2004-04/msg00336.php):

```
CREATE FUNCTION isnumeric(text) RETURNS boolean AS '
SELECT $1 ~ ''^[0-9]+$''
' LANGUAGE 'sql';
```